# AS2 to AS3 Migration, Handling code left on buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, migration, actionscript-2

I have several (20-30) Flash files that I need to migrate from AS2 to AS3.  The biggest issue that I'm having is that it's extremely tedious to go through all the code and change the places where the code is on the buttons to an event handler model.

I'm not hopeful, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any tricks or tools to quickly change all the code on a button in AS2 to AS3 compliant code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Porting 20-30 Flash files between versions is no small task - good luck to you. As you suspect, you probably won't find any shortcuts for this. Just make sure to move all the code into external classes as you go so you never have this problem again. I guess you don't have the option of just loading in the AS2 swfs to a AS3 container?

Comment: Keep your MovieExplorer handy. It'll streamline a bit by helping you to find all the code that needs to be moved. Other than that, I think Iain's pretty much nailed it.

Comment: That is a crying shame.  Thanks for the reply though.  I really wish I could just load the AS2 files, but unfortunately, there's more to it than that.

Comment: JSFL will let you do this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Well i would suggest not sure that you should use any good decompiler and that decompiler can convert your as2 code to as3.. Try and good-luck.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't worked on this in a while, but this JSFL library might be of some use:

[gthmb_as2_converter.zip](http://greenethumb.com/files/gthmb_as2_converter.zip)

it can parse through an single file (FLA or class file) or a folder of files and does its best to convert from as2 to as3. it won't cover everything, but it takes care of most of the tedious stuff. i wrote it because I was tired of having to do all this crap by hand when our designers would hand me AS2 projects and say 'make it AS3' :)

let me know if it helps. there is a basic README file in the zip that tells ya how to use it. pretty simple stuff: run one of the conversion jsfl scripts and follow the prompts.

i dont think it will be able to handlers like:

```
on (release)
{
    //blargh
}
```

but if you do: `mybtn.onRelease = function()...` it will take care of that.

Comment: I'm trying to get "gthmb_as2_converter.zip" to work under Flash CS4 and CS5.5 with no luck. This would be amazing if it works! Can someone comment on this?